# mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(mSocket)) - в сокет ничего не отправляется

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Есть `Service`. В нём есть код, записывающий видео с задней камеры при помощи `android.media.MediaRecorder`:

```
this.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder()
this.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(VideoSource.CAMERA);
this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(photo_resolution[0], photo_resolution[1]); // "photo_resolution"  - глобальная переменная размера фотографии камеры
this.mParcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(this.mSocket);
this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
this.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
this.mMediaRecorder.prepare();
this.mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Видео записываю без звука. Соединение с сервером устанавливаю следующим образом:

```
this.mSocket = new Socket();
this.mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(...), 30000);
this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.mSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
this.out = this.mSocket.getOutputStream();
this.out.write(("some string" + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
this.out.flush();
```

Все необходимые разрешения в `AndroidManifest.xml` добавлены.

Проблема заключается в том, что видео не транслируется в `Socket`. Я пробовал заменить `this.mParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()` на `"/sdcard/video.mp4"` - всё замечательно записывалось и воспроизводилось. А в сокет на сервер не хочет, просто ничего не отправляется, и, в итоге на сервере вылетает исключение `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: read timed out`. В чём ошибка? Как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParcelFileDescriptor` может отправлять видео только в `android.net.LocalSocket`, но не `java.net.Socket`. То бишь, можно сделать следующим образом:

```
private LocalServerSocket mLocalServerSocket;
...
this.mLocalServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket("Имя");
...
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                LocalSocket mLocalSocket = mLocalServerSocket.accept();
                InputStream mInputStream = mLocalSocket.getInputStream();
                while (true) {
                    byte[] i1 = new byte[1048576];
                    int i2 = mInputStream.read(i1, 0, 1048576);
                    if (i2 < 0) {
                        i2.this.out.flush();
                        mInputStream.close();
                        mLocalSocket.close();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        out.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(i1, 0, i2));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        }
    }

}).start();
```

- Создать локальный сервер с произвольным именем (например, `String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())`).
- Инициализировать `MediaRecorder`:

  ```
  mLocalSocket.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("Имя"));
  ...
  this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mLocalSocket.getFileDescriptor());
  ```

  *Если нужно записывать видео несколько раз, то бишь начать трансляцию на сервер, потом закончить, и потом опять несколько раз транслировать, то нужно не забыть про следующие строки:*

  ```
  private boolean isBroadcasting = true; // транслируется ли в данный момент видео на сервер
  private boolean stopVideo = false; // пришёл ли сигнал об остановке трансляции

  if (this.isBroadcasting && this.stopVideo) {
      this.isBroadcasting = false;
      this.stopVideo = false;
      try {
          this.mMediaRecorder.stop(); // остановить запись видео
      } catch (Exception e1) {
      }
      try {
          out.flush(); // отправить последние недостающие байты на сервер
      } catch (Exception e1) {
      }
      try {
          mLocalSocket.close(); // закрыть соединение с локальным сервером,
          // иначе при повторном соединении вылетит исключение "java.io.IOException: already connected"
      } catch (Exception e1) {
      }
  }
  ```

  **Обязательно возвести каждый код в отдельный `try {} catch {}` блок!**, *потому что у `MediaRecorder` не редко происходят ошибки доступа к камере или аудио, следовательно (рассмотрим вариант, если камеры в данный момент недоступна): пришёл сигнал о начале трансляции; соединение с локальным сокетом установлено; видео не транслируется; пришёл сигнал об остановке трансляции; если последний код, где `private boolean isBroadcasting ...` будет возведён в один `try {} catch {}` блок, то, так как `this.mMediaRecorder.stop();` выбросит исключение `IllegalStateException`, то код отключения от локального сервера `mLocalSocket.close();` будет unreachable (недостигаемым); затем, починим камеру, и при попытке снова начать трансляцию, сразу вылетит исключение `java.io.IOException: already connected`; даже если возвести код подключения к локальному серверу `mLocalSocket.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("Имя"));` в отдельный `try {} catch {}` блок, то видео будет транслироваться в никуда, и поможет только перезапуск `Service`; в этом нет смысла.*